# javascript / how to set the same value in nth-child of 2 classes

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, var

https://codepen.io/jh-ko/pen/OBrMOO

```
 var table = [1, "red", 3, 
              4, "blue", 6];
  for (var i = 0; i < table.length; i += 3) {
 var x = table[i];
 var y = table[i+1];
 $(".Ali:nth-child(" + (x++) + ")").click(function() {
 $("div .me:nth-child(" + (x++) + ")").css("color", y);
});
}
```

--There is an example (codepen) on the top.--

I have 2 classes
.Ali and .me

First of all, i want to have the same nth-child value of both classes.
For example, when i click nth-child(1) of Ali class ,
i want to get the color red in nth-child(1) of me class.

but i get a blue in this code,  ...

When i code it just with number directly, it works well.

```
".Ali:nth-child(4)"
"div .me:nth-child(4)"
```

My Goal:
When i click a number (for example 3) in Group A,
i want to have the color on the same number in Group B..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, here is a working solution:

```
var table = ["red", "yellow", "pink", "blue", "green", "gold"];

$(".Ali").click(function() {
   var i = $(this).index();
   $("div .me").eq(i).css("color", table[i]);
 });
```

Your problem is the "x" variable that assumes a different value the second time you use it.

The order of execution is this:

- First iteration (for):

  1. i is 0
  2. x is table[0] = 1
  3. you assign an action to ".Ali:nth-child(1)
  4. x is x++ = 2
  5. y is table[1] = "red"
- Second iteration (for)

  1. i is 3
  2. x is table[3] = 4
  3. you assign an action to ".Ali:nth-child(4)
  4. x is x++ = 5
  5. y is table[5] = "blue"
- On first click

  1. x is 5
  2. you change color to $("div .me:nth-child(5)")
  3. the color is "blue"
- On second click

  1. x is 6, you change color to $("div .me:nth-child(6)")
  2. the color is "blue"
- And so on...

If you use global variables, such as your x and y, every change is global.

Answer (score 0):

Can you query the index of the element being clicked and compare that to the index of the element you want to retrieve data from?

With `.index()` you can find where in clicked element exists in its order.  With `.eq()`/`:eq()` you can target elements by their index within their group.

```js
$('.me').click(function(){
  let i = $(this).index();
  i = i-1;
  console.log( $(`.ali:eq(${i})`).css('background-color') );
});
```

```css
.ali, .me{
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
}

.me{ background-color: black; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="me"></div>
<div class="me"></div>
<div class="me"></div>
<div class="me"></div>
<div class="me"></div>
<div class="me"></div>
<div class="me"></div>
<div class="me"></div>
<div class="me"></div>

<div style="clear: both; width: 100%; "></div>

<div class="ali" style="background-color: red;"></div>
<div class="ali" style="background-color: rebeccapurple;"></div>
<div class="ali" style="background-color: blue;"></div>
<div class="ali" style="background-color: green;"></div>
<div class="ali" style="background-color: yellow;"></div>
<div class="ali" style="background-color: orange;"></div>
<div class="ali" style="background-color: red;"></div>
<div class="ali" style="background-color: rebeccapurple;"></div>
<div class="ali" style="background-color: blue;"></div>
```